# C# - Using protobuf to write directly into a zip file

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, system.io.packaging

I am working on a simulator program that writes small data (<1kB) frequently (> 10 times a second) in a file. I used a Queue to store these data and when this queue had 300 members or more, it'll write data to a file stored in a zip file and clear the queue.

The problem is after pausing or stopping simulation (in both cases `flush` will be called)  when i extract the zip file and check output files (more specificly: `Offsets.sdo`) only data from the last step of writing (in my code, calling `flush`) is inside the file. Also during the simulation Zipfile that i create (with `outFile` field) has size of 0.

My file writer code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Net.Mime;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace SEWS.History
{
    class HistoryWriterEngine : HistoryEngine ,HistoryWriter
    {
        public static readonly string OUTPUT_DATA_FILE_NAME = "SimulationOutdata.sod";
        public static readonly string OFFSETS_FILE_NAME = "Offsets.sdo";

        #region buffer
        private static readonly int MAXIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE = 300; // half a minute of simulation with 0.1s steps
        private Queue<SEWS.SimulationEngine.SimulationOutputData> buffer = new Queue<SEWS.SimulationEngine.SimulationOutputData>();
        private Dictionary<string, PackagePart> packageParts = new Dictionary<string, PackagePart>();
        #endregion

        #region IO
        private ZipPackage outFile;
        public override void initFile(string address)
        {
            if (outFile != null)
            {
                flush();
                closeFile();
            }
            workingFile = address;

            outFile = (ZipPackage)ZipPackage.Open(workingFile, FileMode.Create);

            getNewStream(OUTPUT_DATA_FILE_NAME);
            getNewStream(OFFSETS_FILE_NAME, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
        }

        public override void closeFile()
        {
            flush();
            outFile.Flush();
            outFile.Close();
            outFile = null;
        }

        public Stream getNewStream(string fileName, string type = MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)
        {
            PackagePart packagePart;
            packagePart = outFile.CreatePart(
                PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative)),
                type,
                CompressionOption.SuperFast);

            packageParts.Add(fileName, packagePart);
            return packagePart.GetStream();
        }

        public Stream getStream(string fileName)
        {
            if (packageParts.ContainsKey(fileName))
            {
                return (packageParts[fileName] as PackagePart).GetStream();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("No such file as " + fileName + " found.");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region HistoryWriterImpl
        public void writeOutputData(SEWS.SimulationEngine.SimulationOutputData data)
        {
            buffer.Enqueue(data);
            if (buffer.Count >= MAXIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                flush();
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        public void flush()
        {
            Stream outStream = getStream(OUTPUT_DATA_FILE_NAME);
            Stream offsetsStream = getStream(OFFSETS_FILE_NAME);
            StreamWriter offsetsWriter = new StreamWriter(offsetsStream);

            SEWS.SimulationEngine.SimulationOutputData currentData;
            Console.WriteLine("Writing " + buffer.Count + " records");
            s.Restart();
            while (buffer.Count > 0)
            {
                currentData = buffer.Dequeue();
                Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(outStream, currentData, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
                offsetsWriter.Write(
                    new StringBuilder()
                    .Append(currentData.CurrentStep.ToString())
                    .Append(' ')
                    .Append(currentData.CurrentTime.TimeSinceStart.ToString())
                    .Append(' ')
                    .Append(outStream.Position)
                    .Append("\r\n")
                    .ToString()
                );
            }
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Took " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");

            outStream.Flush();
            offsetsWriter.Flush();
            offsetsStream.Flush();
            outStream.Close();
            offsetsWriter.Close();
            offsetsStream.Close();

            outFile.Flush();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Writing 300 records
Took 138 ms.
Writing 300 records
Took 18 ms.
Writing 300 records
Took 14 ms.
Writing 300 records
Took 14 ms.
Writing 300 records
Took 14 ms.
Writing 41 records
Took 5 ms.
```

First 5 writes are automatic and the last one (41 records) is regarding to a pause in simulation.

Comment: Looks overly complex, TL;DR. But what part do you think means "Open in Append mode" ? I only see new files being made, overwriting the previous ones.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i call `getNewStream` only once. this function creates files in archive.

Comment: Once per `flush()`, so a new file each time `buffer.Count >= MAXIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE`

Comment: @HenkHolterman I guess similarity of names of `getNewStream` and `getStream` confused you! I double checked with VisualStudio's call hierarchy, `getNewStream` is only called in `initFile`. It stores the files in `packageParts` dictionary so that everytime i call `flush` i will reuse `PackagePart.getStream()` that is stored there.

Comment: This is a large sample, but : I dont think the issue relates to Protobuf-net. Forget about serialisation for a moment: if you write a few hundred arbitrary bytes of your choosing to the output stream (in place of serializing): can you get *that* back reliably? I'm guessing you'll find: no

Comment: @MarcGravell Are you saying that streams are not reliable?

Comment: Yes, TL;DR like I said. But I noticed the `outStream.Close();` so my argument still stands. I guess `PackagePart().GetStream()` also creates a File, where you don't expect it to.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's a good guess. I'll try it. (Not calling `getStream()` each time)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes. `PackagePart.getStream()` creates a new file each time. Post an answer, consider it accepted :) Thank you.

Comment: @mJafar not in the least: I'm saying that the code in the question us simply wrong, unrelated to serialization

Comment: @MarcGravell I wasn't sure if it's realted to how protobuf writes in stream and it's some very special case that protobuf behaves abnormal or related to how i use streams or related to another problem, so i tagged and added protobuf in the title too.

Comment: Protobuf-net doesn't do anything unusual with streams - it doesn't even seek etc. Forwards only basic write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code repeatedly calls `flush()` and the intention inside `flush()` seems to be to reuse a file through `getStream()` .

But at the tail end of `flush()` there is a call to `outStream.Close();` and from that it follows that  `getStream()` must always be creating a new file. In Overwrite mode apparently.